# Magento2: How to apply discount on all cart items programatically

Tags: magento2, cart, frontend, discount

I want to add a discount on cart items for the specific customer.

Comment: do you want to give fixed price or % wise discount

Comment: I want to set a custom % discount for a whole cart for a specific customer. @AdarshShukla

Comment: ok i will ansswer please wait for a while

Comment: check my answer

Comment: Ok, I will check and update you soon. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Achieve this by plugin Concept provided in magento 2

step 1: create etc/di.xml with following code

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product">
        <plugin name="give_discount" type="Aadi\Module\Plugin\GiveDiscount" />
    </type>
</config>
```

step 2: create Plugin/GiveDiscount with following code

```
<?php

namespace Aadi\Module\Plugin;

class GiveDiscount
{

    public function afterGetPrice(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject, $result)
    {
        $om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $customerSession = $om->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
        if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            $id=$customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();
            if ($id=2) {//Your customer id
            return $result+500;//Your logic of percentage
            }
        }else{
            return $result;
        }

    }

}
```

Remember to replace Aadi/Module with your Vendor/module respectively.

Comment if any issue;
Thanks, :-)

Comment: How to showing discount to the customer on cart page which we added the discount.

Comment: cart means check out cart

Comment: No, item cart page.

Comment: add screen short of place in question or make other question

Comment: Now, I have added a 10% discount to the customer but customer can't understand 10% added to the customer. Only subtotal are changed.

Comment: Please check the link https://ibb.co/qWmGr8b

Comment: create another Question i will answer it

Comment: @AdarshShukla, is there any way to set discount amount on each quote items?

Comment: @jafarpinjar what you want to do?

Comment: @AdarshShukla, I am trying to apply discount amount to each quote item rather than applying the discount to whole cart

Comment: @jafarpinjar add condition accordingly

Comment: @AdarshShukla, how that can be done? can you elaborate it pls, i just asked a new question on that.pls update me your answer

Comment: @AdarshShukla, did you see my new question about this?